# Error while using Multiprocessing.Pool in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I tried all the options but not able to find the issue with below code, it works when i call the sub self.ProcessXmlFile(xml_file) but throws below error with multiprocessing when i print result_list:

> ```
> cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
> ```

```
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
            result_list = []
            for xml_file in os.listdir(self.local_folder):
                    result_list.append(pool.apply_async(self.ProcessXmlFile, args = (xml_file,)))
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

Comment: nair, can you show the ProcessXMLFile code???

Comment: Figured out the issue, instead of defining ProcessXMLFile as class method, I have declared it outside the class and I am able to use pool.apply_async to call the fuction.